# SQL JOIN with Date filtering Best Practice

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to accomplish the following task in Oracle sql:

Return only the rows from Table1 whose start and end dates are spanned by the star and end dates in Table2.

```
Table 2:
 ------------------------------------
| uid | startdate |enddate | typenum |
 ------------------------------------
| 123 | 09/1/22   | 09/3/22 | 25     |
```

Any rows from table 1 that overlap Table 2 start and end dates should be returned. Example:

```
Table 1 - qualified rows:
 ------------------------------------
| uid | startdate |enddate | typenum |
 ------------------------------------
| 123 | 09/1/22   | 09/3/22 | 10    |        
| 123 | 09/2/22   | 09/6/22 | 30    |  
| 123 | 08/28/22   | 08/30/22 | 25    |
| 123 | 09/4/22   | 09/5/22 | 25    |

Table 1 - disqualified rows:
 ------------------------------------
| uid | startdate |enddate | typenum |
 ------------------------------------
| 123 | 09/1/22   | 09/3/22 | 25     |        
| 123 | 09/2/22   | 09/6/22 | 25     |  
| 123 | 08/30/22   | 09/2/22 | 25    |
| 123 | 08/30/22   | 09/7/22 | 25    |
```

This query works, but can it be more optimized and cleaned ?

```
Select * From Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2  T2 ON T1.uid = T2.uid
AND T1.typenum = 25
AND ( 
    ( T1.startdate BETWEEN T2.startdate AND T2.endate OR T1.endate BETWEEN T2.startdate AND 
    T2.endate )
    OR ( T1.startdate >  T2.startdate AND T1.endate < T2.endate )
    OR ( T1.startdate <  T2.startdate AND T1.endate > T2.endate )
    )
```

Comment: mysql <> oracle. Both may lead to completely different solutions. What's the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: @lemon oracle. updated in the description to clarify.

Comment: Please show us the schema and indexes for both tables, as well as the `explain` for the query.

Comment: Would a start and end of 9/2/22 be a match?

Comment: Yes. since they are spanned by table 2 start and end dates.

Comment: You're doing this date range overlap match effectively, I believe. It's not a simple filter. You might take this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It looks fine to me as long as you can assume that startdate < enddate always. 
 I think the OR clause starting with t1.startdate > t2.start is superfluous since any time it is true the between statements is true.

Comment: @RobertHamilton That way necessary to cover case when T2 range is spanned by T1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test for spans which *don't* intersect, there's only two options.

```
*---*
     *---*

     *---*
*---*
```

Let's write a test for that. They don't intersect if one event starts after the other.

```
t1.end < t2.start OR
t2.end < t1.start
```

To test for intersection, we negate it.

```
NOT(
  t1.end < t2.start OR
  t2.end < t1.start
)
```

And we can apply [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to get rid of the not.

```
t1.end >= t2.start AND
t2.end >= t1.start
```

Let's look at all the possibilities. The end of one span always has to be the same or after the start of the other.

```
*----*     ✓
*----*

*----*     ✓
  *----*

  *----*   ✓
*----*

*-----*    ✓
 *---*

*-----*    ✓
 *---*
```